How send transaction using PHP?
What am I doing wrong?

$transaction = [
    'recentBlockhash' => getRecentBlockhash(),
    'instructions' => [
        'programId' => 11111111111111111111111111111111,
        'keys' => [
            [
                'pubkey' => $from, //base58 encoded
                'isSigner' => true,
                'isWritable' => true,
            ],
            [
                'pubkey' => $to, //base58 encoded
                'isSigner' => false,
                'isWritable' => true,
            ],
            [
                'pubkey' => 11111111111111111111111111111111,
                'isSigner' => false,
                'isWritable' => true,
            ],
        ],
        'data' => base64_encode(pack('C', 3) . pack('P', $amount)),
    ],
    'signers' => [$from], //base58 encoded
    'feePayer' => $from, //base58 encoded
    'nonceInformation' => null,
];

$secret = base58_decode($private);
$signature = sodium_crypto_sign_detached(json_encode($transaction), $secret);

$signedTransaction = [
    'transaction' => $transaction,
    'signature' => base58_encode($signature)
];

// send this using cURL
$data = [
    'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
    'id' => time(),
    'method' => 'sendTransaction',
    'params' => [
        base58_encode(json_encode($signedTransaction)),
    ],
];

Error: failed to deserialize solana_sdk::transaction::versioned::VersionedTransaction: io error: failed to fill whole buffer

Transactions have a very precise format to be accepted by the network -- unfortunately it's more involved than a base-58 encoded json struct. You may want to see how a PHP library like https://github.com/Attestto-com/solana-php-sdk does it, or learn about the Solana transaction format at https://solana.com/docs/core/transactions#transaction
